# Get index of a value

Tags: java, hashmap

I am having an input like this.

```
0 Overcast Yes  4
0 Rainy Yes 3
0 Sunny No  3
1 Cool No   1
1 Cool Yes  3
```

I am trying to store these data in a Hashmap

```
{0=[Overcast Yes 4,Rainy Yes    3,Sunny No  3]}
{1=[Cool No 1,Cool Yes  3]}
```

So far what I did is

```
        Map<String, List<String>> mapPart = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while((partLine = bfpart.readLine())!=null){
            String restOfString="";
            String[] first = partLine.split(" ");
            String firstPart = first[0];
            for (int i=1; i<first.length; i++)
            {
                restOfString += first[i];
                restOfString += " ";
            }
            if(mapPart.isEmpty()){
                tmpList.add(restOfString);
                mapPart.put(firstPart, tmpList);
            }
            else{
                for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : mapPart.entrySet()) {
              String colId = entry.getKey();
              if(colId.equals(firstPart)){
                 List<String> lst = mapPart.get(colId);
                 lst.add(restOfString);
                 mapPart.put(colId,lst);
              }
              else{ //should we craete a new list
              }
            }

        }
```

current output

```
map: {0=[Overcast Yes   4 , Rainy No    2 ,  Sunny No   3 ]}
```

I am trying to calculate this equation.

`Info(n)=([no.of yes for overcast,no.of No for overcast],[no.of yes for Rainy,no.of no for Rainy],[no.of yes for Sunny,no.of no for Sunny])`

```
Info0([4,0],[3,0],[0,3])/log2
Info1([3,1])/log2
```

1. Is the above a good way to do with this equation
2. or while reading the file itself the equation can be done or not ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Replace the existing value or something?

Comment: You should definitely check what a `Map` represents and what it is good for - I think you mistake a map for a list.

Comment: @mvreijn: I am trying to get the output as "{0=[Overcast Yes 4,Rainy Yes    3,Sunny No  3],1=[Cool No   1,Cool Yes  3]}"

Comment: Could you please explain your goal in more details? A couple of input/output examples ware also not bad.

Comment: for each column id I want to find the above equation "Info(n)"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate over entire hash map. This is an idea of the map, that you can search by key very efficiently:

```
List<String> list = mapPart.get(firstPart);
if (list == null) {
    // first time using this index
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    mapPart.put(firstPart, list);
}
list.add(restOfString);
```

(Replace your `for (Map.Entry<...` loop with this snippet)

Comment: Showing "Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to String" in mapPart.get(firstPart)

Comment: Sorry, try it again, please. The type of `list` should be `List<String>` of course

Comment: Am I able to get the values seperatly .pls see my edit

Answer (score 0):

There is a more simple/readable way of doing it

```
List<String> value = mapPart.get(firstPart); //1. Get the List<String> for the key
if(value == null) { //2. If it doesn't exist, then create and put it against the key
    value = new ArrayList<String>();
    mapPart.put(first, value);
}
value.add(restOfString); //3. Finally add the values for the key
```

Comment: Thanks Sanbhat: and in else part we need to create a new entry.In current given answer we will only get o values

Answer (score 0):

HashMap does not store the values based on indices. You don't need the index there. you could do something like this.

```
else{
 for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : mapPart.entrySet()) {
  String colId = entry.getKey();
  if(colId.equals(firstPart)){
     List<String> lst = get(colId);
     lst.add(restOfString);
     mapPart.put(colId,lst);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Map<String,List<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, boolean). mapPart.get(colId).add(restOfString) is boolean

Comment: Edited the answer to add the list.